# Lighting-Reflectance Models & Licensing Issues

Tags: licensing

Generally, or specifically, is there any licensing issue with using any of the well known lighting/reflectance models (i.e. the BRDFs or other distribution or approximation functions):

> Phong, Blinn–Phong, Cook–Torrance, Blinn-Torrance-Sparrow, Lambert,
>   Minnaert, Oren–Nayar, Ward, Strauss, Ashikhmin-Shirley

and common modifications where applicable, such as:

> Beckmann distribution, Blinn distribution, Schlick's approximation,
>   etc.

in your shader code utilised in a commercial product? Or is it a non-issue?

Answer (score 4):

In the US, pure mathematical formulae cannot be copyrighted or patented ([reference](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/documents/2100_2106_02.htm)), so no, there is no issue with any of the lighting models you mentioned.

A specific piece of software implementing such a formula could be copyrighted or patented, but the formulae themselves are unencumbered and can be freely used to create your own implementation.

(Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.)